# Trying to use forEach to add up values in my array - would I be better be using a for loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach

Apologies for the beginner question.

I'm used to use for loop and thought I would give a `forEach` function a try.

What I don't understand is that within the function, I need to declare my `finalCount` to zero but obviously it will get reset/cleared.

If I declare it before the function, obviously, it won't be accessible.

So I guess my question is that would a forEach be best or I should just stick to what I know best - the for loop

Code below.

```
items.forEach(function(item) {
  var count = 0
  var itemAmount = parseInt(item.itemRRPAmount);
  console.log(itemAmount)
  console.log("Item amount is: " + itemAmount)
  var count = itemAmount + count
  console.log("Final count = " + count)
})
```

Comment: `If I declare it before the function, obviously, it won't be accessible.` this is not true.

Comment: I tried the following without luck

`var count = 0
items.forEach(function(item){
var itemAmount = parseInt(item.itemRRPAmount);
console.log(itemAmount)
console.log("Item amount is: "+itemAmount)
var count = itemAmount + count
console.log("Final count = " + count)
})`

Comment: You shouldn't redeclare `var count` inside the function if you're trying to access the one outside. That's where it went wrong, it's not that the outer scope is inherently inaccessible.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're iterating over all array items to combine into a single output value, it might be even more preferable to use `reduce`, which does not require any reassignment of variables, and is quite efficiently terse, which is pretty useful:

```
const totalCount = items.reduce((a, { itemRRPAmount }) => a + itemRRPAmount, 0);
```

Or, with `forEach`, the above would look like:

```
let totalCount = 0;
items.forEach(({ itemRRPAmount }) => {
  totalCount += itemRRPAmount;
});
```

Or, if you don't like destructuring:

```
let totalCount = 0;
items.forEach((item) => {
  totalCount += item.itemRRPAmount;
});
```